# Automatically refresh access token with django-social-auth (omab)

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, django-socialauth

I am currently using django-social-auth to manage oauth2 registration with google-oauth2 for access to Google Drive. I have added offline access to my extra_arguments. Therefore Google returns a refresh token and it is stored by django-social-auth. The problem is that django-social-auth never uses this refresh token to update the access token. Therefore the access token expires after one hour, and I can't use it to perform offline requests. I want to keep the access_token valid 24/7 so I can keep my database synced with each users Google Drive.

```
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {'access_type':'offline'}
GOOGLE_OAUTH_EXTRA_SCOPE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile']

SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.GoogleDriveUser'
SOCIAL_AUTH_EXTRA_DATA = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_SESSION_EXPIRATION = False
```

Is there a way to force django-social auth to update the access_token every time it expires using the refresh_token. I would love to see an example of how this problem could be solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like UserSocialAuth objects [now have a .refresh_token() method](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/issues/492), which allows you to use .tokens and get the updated token.

Comment: Sorry, is this mean that this `.refresh_token` will be called automatically when `access token` will expire? Or I need manually somehow know that token expired?

Comment: @user3479125 I believe it should refresh automatically, however this also allows you to catch such exceptions and refresh yourself if it doesn't in certain edge cases :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no way directly implemented in django-social-auth at the moment (I've raised a ticket to track it https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/issues/492), meanwhile [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/3906451) will do the work, it just need to be improved a little to suite your needs.